# What is the purpose behind these three very similar methods of a LinkedList?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I'm looking through the Java 8 documentation for `LinkedList`, and I see several methods that appear to do the same thing. For example:

1. add(E e):
   Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
2. addLast(E e):
   Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
3. offer(E e):
   Adds the specified element as the tail (last element) of this list.

These three appear to all do the same thing. I see that `add` and `offer` both return booleans signifying whether the modification was successful or not.

The docs for `add` even say it is the same as `addLast`, although it doesn't return anything. I guess I'm wondering why all this redundancy? When would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LinkedList` implements several interfaces:

- `add` comes from the `List` and `Queue` interfaces, which get it from `Collection`;
- `offer` comes from the `Queue` interface, and differs from the `add` method in terms of what it does on failure (described [in a table in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html));
- `addLast` comes from the `Deque` interface. `Deque` is also a `Collection`, and so has the `add` method; perhaps the `addLast` is there for clarity and symmetry with the `addFirst` method, so you're not left in any doubt as to which end `add` is adding to. [As described in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), `Deque.addLast` and `Queue.add` are equivalent.

In terms of which you should choose: pretty much up to you, since they do the same thing (give or take a return type).

---

The bigger question is: why does `LinkedList` try to be so many things (not very single-responsibility-principle, is it?); and should you be using that at all?

There's a [thread on Twitter](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248) where Josh Bloch - the author of `java.util.LinkedList` - questions whether it is actually useful at all. He suggests that you are better off using `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque`, depending on exactly what you need it to do.

Comment: `add` should come originally from `Collection`... `Queue` also has `add`